# Generate a JSON file from keyless list in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, list

I've been doing some web-scraping recently and ultimately fetched the data I wanted. However, there is no sense of organization since it's only a simple list in Python. It contains the meeting type (either LE/DI/SE), days, time, professor's name (edited for privacy), among some other values.

```
["LE", "A00", "MWF", "10:00a-10:50a", "MLK", "AUD", "Smith, John", "976539", "DI", "A01", "F", "5:00p-5:50p", "MLK", "AUD", "Smith, John", "FULL Waitlist(25)", "216", "FI", "03/17/2018", "S", "8:00a-10:59a", "TBA", "TBA", "LE", "B00", "MWF", "1:00p-1:50p", "WLH", "2005", "Smith, John", "927471", "DI", "B01", "F", "6:00p-6:50p", "MLK", "AUD", "Smith, John", "FULL Waitlist(32)", "200", "FI", "03/17/2018", "S", "8:00a-10:59a", "TBA", "TBA"]
```

As you can see, it's an ugly list. My goal is to make it something like this:

```
{
  "MATH101": {
    "LE": {

      sectionCode: 'A00',
      days: 'MFW',
      times: '10:00a-10:50am',
      building: 'MLK',
      room: 'AUD',
      instructor: 'Smith, John',

      "DI": {
        sectionCode: 'A01',
        days: 'F',
        times: '5:00-5:50pm',
        building: 'MLK',
        room: 'AUD',
        instructor: 'Smith, John',
        availableSeats: 'FULL Waitlist(25)',
        capacity: '216'
      }
    },

    "LE": {

      sectionCode: 'B00',
      days: 'MFW',
      times: '1:00a-1:50pm',
      building: 'MLK',
      room: 'AUD',
      instructor: 'Smith, John',

      "DI": {
        sectionCode: 'B01',
        days: 'F',
        times: '6:00-6:50pm',
        building: 'MLK',
        room: 'AUD',
        instructor: 'Smith, John',
        availableSeats: 'FULL Waitlist(32)',
        capacity: '200'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is a discussion per lecture section, thus there are two lecture times and two discussions that pertain to each lecture. I don't know if there is a better schema to store this data, but I could only come up with this.

I thought iterating through the list and saving values starting after the "LE" or "DI" strings into the ordered way that I established above, but I don't see how that would help me create the json file without each key.

I'm new to all this, and I haven't been able to find a solution. Tried converting into dictionary but it doesn't meet my needs. A lot of data is also repeated, such as the professor's name, but there won't always be one professor, nor two lectures/discussions. I plan to do this with all the courses available, so this just gets more and more complicated...

Hopefully someone is able to help out, thank you!

Comment: Is the order in the initial list guaranteed ? Are you trying to do the transformation in Python or JS ?

Comment: Why don't you put everything in a suitable data structure when you're doing the scraping?

Comment: There may be an arbitrary number as a first element sometimes, but generally the order always goes the same: Type, section, days, time, building, room, available seats, capacity.

It can be either in Python or JS, though I've been using Python for all the scraping.

Comment: What are some of those suitable data structures I could use? And how will I be able to order them in the way I want it to? I'm unsure how to do this.

Comment: Your scraping code should return the final data you want rather than a simple flat array.